# Question related to ordinal number without using Axiom of Choice.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Can we proof this result without using Axiom of Choice :-
$$A\cap \alpha=\emptyset  \,\,\,\, \mbox{and}\, \, \, A\times \alpha \sim A\cup \alpha$$ then there is an $A^{'} \subset A$ such that $\alpha \sim A^{'}$ or $B\subset \alpha$ such that $A\sim B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is Tarski's lemma with which he proved that $\kappa^2=\kappa$ implies the axiom of choice.

Suppose that $f\colon A\cup\alpha\to A\times\alpha$ is a bijection. Either for every $a\in A$ there is some $\beta<\alpha$ such that $f(\beta)=(a,\gamma)$, in which case consider the map $a\mapsto\min\{\beta\mid\exists\gamma\ f(\beta)=(a,\gamma)\}$, then by the fact that $f$ is a bijection this map is injective from $A$ into $\alpha$.

If this is not the case, then there is some $a$ such that $f^{-1}\Big(\{a\}\times\alpha\Big)\subseteq A$ and this defines an injection from $\alpha$ into $A$.

Comment: Halfway through writing this I realized that it's a bit simpler to take $f\colon A\times\alpha\to A\cup\alpha$ instead. I encourage you, in order to understand this argument better, to try and reform the proof using a function in the "correct" direction.

Comment: Thanks,so do you say this question is equivalent to Tarski's Lemma?

Comment: I never used the word "equivalent". I said this is the lemma that Tarski used to conclude the axiom of choice *from* the assumption $\kappa^2=\kappa$ for all infinite $\kappa$.

Comment: Thanks.now Its clear to me.